# Enable back button when return from facebook.com, phonegap android

Tags: android, cordova

I am developing a phonegap android app, where I have initially disabled the back button of device using this, its working

```
document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKey, false);

function onBackKey(){

}
```

But, when I click on a button in my app to goto facebook login page, I want the back button to be enabled. I tried to remove event listener but it didn't work

```
funtion f_click(url, width, height){
   document.removeEventListener("backbutton", onBackKey, false);  
   //some link to start facebook
}
```

I also used

```
document.removeEventListener("backbutton", function(e) { e.preventDefault(); }, false);
```

But I am getting this error every time, `cordova is not defined`. Why?

Comment: In your question you have `funtion f_click` - is that a typo or is the c also missing in your real code?

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to call the "**deviceready**" event.

From phonegap doc :

> This is a very important event that every Cordova application should
>   use.
>
> Cordova consists of two code bases: native and JavaScript. While the
>   native code is loading, a custom loading image is displayed. However,
>   JavaScript is only loaded once the DOM loads. This means your web
>   application could, potentially, call a Cordova JavaScript function
>   before it is loaded.
>
> The Cordova deviceready event fires once Cordova has fully loaded.
>   After the device has fired, you can safely make calls to Cordova
>   function.

Try something like this :

```
var deviceReady = false;

document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady()
{
    deviceReady = true;
}

function f_click(url, width, height)
{
    if(deviceReady)
    {
        document.removeEventListener("backbutton", onBackKey, false);
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: gaepi... how can we write a function inside other function, when I tried your solution it gave error - "f_click is not defined"

Comment: Sure ... I edited my post. I don't know if it's the best solution but you have to wait the deviceready callback

Comment: it still didn't worked for me :( , back button is not enabled

Comment: gr8 man it helped me... :) Thanx a lot buddy.. Actually, in the first attempt I forgot to declare "deviceReady".

Comment: Glad to help. Maybe you could validate my answer :)